# criar subdominios dinamicos no registro br

Tags: node.js

Estou usando registro br para meu site e sistema web, na parte do servidor eu uso nodejs e estou tentando criar subdomínios dinâmicos (widcard), ao tentar usar o módulo widcard do nodejs ele simplesmente não me retorna nada. Alguém já trabalhou com o mesmo e tem algum exemplo ou algum outro jeito de fazer isso??

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow, Miguel! Por favor inclua o seu código para que a comunidade possa lhe ajudar no seu problema - e tente explicar melhor o que você tentou fazer, e onde que está dando errado. Aproveite e faça o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para conhecer melhor como o site funciona!

Answer (score 3):

Para habilitar o uso de um subdomínio no node.js, você pode usar o módulo `vhost` junto com o `express`:

```
npm install vhost
```

Inclua ele no seu código, e coloque as rotas dele antes de todas as outras:

```
var vhost = require('vhost');
var admin = express.Router();
app.use(vhost('admin.*', admin));

admin.get('/', function( req, res){
    res.send("hello SOpt!");
});
```

> Segue um exemplo simples, mas completo:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3333);
var vhost = require('vhost');

var admin = express.Router();
var loja = express.Router();

app.use(vhost('admin.*', admin)); 
app.use(vhost('loja.*', loja)); 

admin.get('/', function( req, res){
    res.send("hello admin");
});

loja.get('/', function( req, res){
    res.send("hello loja");
});

app.use(function(req, res){
    res.type('text/plain');
    res.status(404);
    res.send('404 - Pagina Nao Encontrada');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('iniciado em http://localhost:' + app.get('port'));
});
```

> Acesse pela páginas http://admin.localhost:3333 e http://loja.localhost:3333